# How to not expose Traefik port to the internet?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, traefik

I am very new to Traefik and Kubernetes. I installed Traefik through helm (repo: https://traefik.github.io/traefik-helm-chart/, helm version 3.5.2, chart traefik-9.19.1). Then I wanted to get prometheus metrics from it.

Here is an extract of my values.yaml file:

```
ports:
  metrics:
    expose: true
    port: 3333
    exposedPort: 3333
    protocol: TCP

additionalArguments:
  - "--metrics.prometheus=true"
  - "--metrics.prometheus.buckets=0.100000, 0.300000, 1.200000, 5.000000"
  - "--metrics.prometheus.addEntryPointsLabels=true"
  - "--metrics.prometheus.addServicesLabels=true"
  - "--entrypoints.metrics.address=:3333/tcp"
  - "--metrics.prometheus.entryPoint=metrics"
```

My problem is: this configuration exposes the TCP port 3333 to the Internet. For security reasons, I would prefer to avoid this.

Is there a way to expose port 3333 only to my cluster?

Comment: Can you let us know which helm chart you are using?

Comment: If you only want other resources from reaching this app, you should use a `Service` resource. And, if you configure a DNS server inside your cluster, you can reference it from other resources by name, not by its IP. For example, if your `Service` was called `app` and was running on the `production` namespace, you can reach it by the name: `app.production`. `Ingresses` are used to provide external access to your cluster resources.

Comment: please share your full values file. From what you're telling us, if port 3333 is reachable outside of your SDN, my guess is that you have set `.Values.hostNetwork` to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the `expose` and `exposedPort` parameter.

Comment: It makes the port unavailable: prometheus get a timeout ...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ports:
  metrics:
    expose: true
    port: 3333
    exposedPort: 3333
    protocol: TCP

env:
- name: POD_IP
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      apiVersion: v1
      fieldPath: status.podIP

additionalArguments:
- "--metrics.prometheus=true"
- "--metrics.prometheus.buckets=0.100000, 0.300000, 1.200000, 5.000000"
- "--metrics.prometheus.addEntryPointsLabels=true"
- "--metrics.prometheus.addServicesLabels=true"
- "--entrypoints.metrics.address=$(POD_IP):3333/tcp"
- "--metrics.prometheus.entryPoint=metrics"
```

Traefik will expose metrics only at POD_IP network interface.

And/or additionally, i'd propose to update firewall settings at your workers (iptables, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to set a configuration outside of traefik :
I think that you can use something like iptable to block access to this port from outside of your server. Or only accept to this port for a specific sub network.

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 0.0.0.0  -i eth0 --protocol tcp --dport 3333 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

Exposing a traefik port ONLY to other containers in the cluster you have to create a new service and map the ports.

My use case was to expose the /metrics endpoint to other pods without having /metrics accessible on the internet.

DO not change any of the metrics values in the helm chart, it just makes it more confusing to get it initialized. The helm chart will open port 9100 to access /metrics by default without exposing to the internet.

Here is my service to accessing /metrics. To test go into a container and do `curl ${service_cluster_ip}:9100/metrics`

```
# Traefik exposes /metrics on port 9100 and need to let other containers access it.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik-metrics
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: traefik
    app.kubernetes.io/name: traefik-metrics
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - name: traefik
    port: 9100
    targetPort: metrics
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: traefik
    app.kubernetes.io/name: traefik
```

Run the helm install and adding the service should get it to work